# Не могу решить достаточно простую задачу, помогите пожалуйста

Tags: javascript

На фабрике принтер печатает этикетки для коробок. Для одного вида коробок принтер должен использовать цвета, которые обозначаются буквами от a до m. Иногда случаются проблемы, и строка с несуществующими цветами (с буквами не от a до m) может попасть в принтер.

Создай функцию getRatio, которая принимает строку colors, представляющую цвета для принтера, и возвращает частоту ошибок в строке. Результатом должна быть строка с дробью, числитель которой - количество ошибок, а знаменатель - длина строки.

Примечание: строка colors содержит только буквы от a до z.

пробовала разные варианты, также через регулярку, но все не то

```
function getRatio(colors) {
  let error = 0;
  const res = ('abcdefghijklm');
  const sum = colors.length;

  for (let i = 0; i < sum; i++) {
    if (sum[i] !== res) {
      error++;
    }
  }

  return (`${error}/${sum}`);
}
```

Comment: А просто реплейснуть валидные символы на пустую строку? останутся только "ошибки"...

Comment: sum же число. Ну разве сможет быть символ равен длинной строке? Вам же нужно проверить на вхождение в неё (например,  indexOf) или просто colors[i]>"m" или colors[i]<"a" (более эффективно, если это волнует)

Comment: `sum[i] !== res` sum - длина входной строки (colors), вам же надо в условии брать эл-т с входного массива, т.е. colors[i] и смотреть, есть ли в разрешенной строке этот эл-т.  Если не изменять ваш вариант, то единственное что можно поменять это условие `if (sum[i] !== res) {` на `if (!res.includes(colors[i])) {` - смотрим есть ли в строке res символ текущей итерации colors[i]) и ! - символ отрицания, т.е. условие "если в строке нет символа" то инкрементируем кол-во ошибок (error++)

Comment: А за что минус поставили? Вот не понимаю подобного... Человек решает задачу - не получается, есть пример решения, надо просто поправить. За что подобное минусовать?

Answer (score 0):

> принимает строку colors, представляющую цвета для принтера, и возвращает частоту ошибок в строке. Результатом должна быть строка с дробью, числитель которой - количество ошибок, а знаменатель - длина строки.

Предложу такое решение...

```js
console.log(getRatio('dkadltnzmweoui'))
//
function getRatio(colors) {
  const a = [
    colors.replace(/[a-m]/g, '').length,
    colors.length
  ]
  return a.join('/')
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое)